# What is my name?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, history

I ran on the oars,

being a sacred man,

but was tormented to death by Saddam.

---

One associative friend reached fame,

with carrot and stick,

another was shot dead on the street.

---

What is my name?

Hint 1:

> egiLott

Hint 2:

> Four letter name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Olaf

I ran on the oars,

> Olaf Tryggvason was reputed to have done this.

being a sacred man,

> Saint Olaf of Norway.

but was tormented to death by Saddam.

> Not sure about this one

One associative friend reached fame,
with carrot and stick,

> Olaf from the movie 'Frozen'.

another was shot dead on the street

> Possible reference to the assassination of Olof Palme.

Hint 1

> This is an anagram of 'Let it go' - the song from the movie 'Frozen'.

Comment: You should be extremely precise on the spelling of names

Answer (score 2):

**My guess: (1)**

> President of the United States

**Explanation:**

I ran on the oars

> Franklin Pierce won the Harvard-Yale boat race

being a sacred man

> James A. Garfield was a preacher

but was tormented to death by Saddam.

> No idea, likely a reference to George (H.?) W. Bush

One associative friend reached fame

> Associationalism championed by Theodore Roosevelt; perhaps fame refers to Ronald Reagan being an actor.

with carrot and stick

> Nixon using the "carrot-and-stick" approach. The stick could also refer to Theodore Roosevelt's quote "speak softly, and carry a big stick".

another was shot dead on the street.

> Assassination of John F. Kennedy.

Have to admit I don't get the hint, though.

Comment: Good try, but not correct

Comment: @Enigma If I have another attempt, do I edit this post or try another answer?

Comment: @SteamyRoot If it is substantially different, I suggest you post another answer